# is this microservice design fine?

Tags: microservices, spring

I have recently decided upon a micro service design to merge  two Spring Boot applications.

I basically have 2 applications that deliver two entirely different front ends, but share user accounts.

My current structure is (in no particular order):

- Application 1
- Application 2
- Gateway service
- Discovery service

The gateway to the applications is something like:

localhost:8080/application1

OR

localhost:8080/application2.

If you log into one, you are presumably authenticated to both.

In a gist, the application specific pages are delivered through zuul and the gateway handles all of it; however the actual JSPs are inside the specific Spring-Boot application.

Does it make sense to have the web pages delivered to the client inside the gateway service, and the specific application services (1 and 2) just contain the REST calls?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "fine."

Comment: The question as written has trigger words to make people close the question.  For example "Is XXXX design fine/best practice/ideal?" is a trigger word.  If the question was more clearly about converting multiple legacy apps into a unified microservices based app, or clarifying why microservices are built the way they are it would have a better chance.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch: It's not "trigger words," unless by that you mean "those words  that are used when the OP doesn't know what to ask."

Comment: Those are the words that tend to get questions downvoted and closed.  But yes, they are also symptoms of an OP not really sure how to ask the question they really intended to.

Comment: i definitely don't know how to ask the question because I don't understand the ins and outs of the topic. But I don't understand why that should prevent me from asking a question and getting more clarification from people willing to help.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is important to understand what you get with microservices, why infrastructure is needed, and what the cost of microservices are.  That will help inform you if your approach is reasonable, particularly with the goal of unifying to completely different applications.

First, a summary of the trade-offs:

- You have the *opportunity* to **minimize the blast radius** if a service goes offline (i.e. impact to the user)
- You have the *opportunity* to **scale out** dynamically based on load and demand
- You have more moving parts so **deployments are more complex**
- You have the need to centralize how **configuration** works

I want to emphasize the word "opportunity" because there are restrictions to make those opportunities a reality.  Namely that you don't use server side sessions at all.  If you have to maintain state, either do it in the HTML/JavaScript or do it in the database.  You have to simplify the ability to load balance all the instances of a service, and storing information in memory on the server side works against that.

That said, we start to see *why* discovery, configuration, and an API Gateway are necessary.  All of these can be managed in different ways.  The core cloud infrastructure pieces are needed precisely because of microservices.

- **Discovery:** enables you to find all instances of a service by name.  This can be accomplished by using Eureka (Spring Cloud infrastructure), Kubernetes Services, or an App Mesh
- **API Gateway:** a reverse proxy that will map URLs to specific microservices on the backend--providing load balancing across the services.  This can be accomplished by Zuul or SC Gateway (Spring Cloud infrastructure), Kubernetes Ingress service, or an App Mesh
- **Configuration:** a means of managing configuration and pushing updates to the running services.  This can be accomplished by Spring Config Server (Spring Cloud infrastructure), Kubernetes ConfigMaps and Secrets, or an App Mesh.
- **Central Log Management:** is required to understand how your application is behaving in the wild.  Whether you use Elastic Stack, Splunk, Data Dog, or a cloud broker provided service, you will be better equipped to diagnose problems that span multiple microservices.

Before you say "I'll use App Mesh" understand that app mesh is a suite of technologies that integrate with an orchestration layer (like Kubernetes) underneath of it.  You have to understand the concepts of the App Mesh and the underlying technology.  The learning curve very well may be something you don't have the time to take on right now.

**How To Migrate to Microservices**

The pragmatist in me likes the ["strangler pattern"](https://dzone.com/articles/monolith-to-microservices-using-the-strangler-patt).  Essentially, you migrate out specific functionality into its own microservice, and adapt the existing application(s) to leverage that microservice instead of the old way it used to deal with things.  For example, separating out the authentication/authorization functionality into a unified service so that the user's token has all the attributes needed encoded inside of it (see JWT.io) you can minimize service-to-service communication to verify permissions.  That would provide you single-sign-on for your application suite.

But while you are in the design phase, also consider the build vs. buy question.  If you are hosting in the cloud, check your provider if they have services that do everything you need.  For example, single-sign-on is a common need and all the major providers have their version of SSO support.

**Key Takeaway**

Microservices are a powerful way to manage application deployments.  If you are smart about how you design them, you can minimize your cloud expenditures.  I.e. taking advantage of managed services hides the actual compute instances you are leveraging.  The cloud provider handles that so support the SLAs and minimize the cost to the provider, and you get a lower cost solution.  Having a dynamic deployment allows to you take advantage of spot instances for surge activity.

Putting both of your applications behind a common API Gateway does not magically give you single-sign-on.  Nor does it give you any of the real benefits of a microservices architecture.  However, **it is a place to start**.  You can expand on this initial investment over time.  Even the Amazon store front had to evolve from a monolithic application to microservices.  That took time, and it took time learning how the different architectures helped the application scale and minimize the cost of running it.  That is a journey you will have to take if this is the direction your company wants to go.

Comment: This is a good answer that goes into a lot more about how one can practically migrate from monoliths to a microservice ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

I want to first commend you on deciding to think about a microservice design approach.  There are a number of thoughts I have on your approach that you should consider.

> a micro service design to merge two Spring Boot applications.

Right off the bat I think you need to change your perspective on what you really want to accomplish here.  The antonym of microservices is a monolith.  So if I have two applications and choose to merge them together then what I am actually doing is *creating* a monolith.

> Does it make sense to have the web pages delivered to the client inside the gateway service, and the specific application services (1 and 2) just contain the REST calls?

Not in terms of a microservice based architecture.  The key takeaway with a microservice approach is to not think about the totality of your system as a series of highly coupled applications and monoliths.  Instead consider a macro level view of important business and user functionality and design your microservices around each of these specific concerns.

For example, consider the following high level user experience for a shopping app:

- Customer should be able to authenticate themselves.
- Customer should be able to update their profile
- Customer should be able to update their payment card info
- Customer should be able to search for inventory
- Customer should be able to add items to the cart
- Customer should be able to complete checkout.

In an overly simplified way, I might think about the microservices as having a single responsibility over a single business domain:

- User Authentication/Identity Provider: Probably an implementation of OIDC/OAuth as an Identity Provider service.
- Customer Details: CRUD operations for a Customer
- Payment Gateway: Probably contains an interface to a third party payment processor
- Inventory - Inventory management services
- Customer Shopping Session - Customer shopping session details like the shopping cart.  Probably interfaces with Customer Detail services and Inventory services.
- Checkout/Order - Services that complete a checkout.  Interfaces with Customer Shopping session, Customer Details, Payment Gateway, and inventory management.
- Customer Experience: Provides presentation level services/mobile app/ web front end?

So these would be a good example of a series of service domains that may or may not need to be split even more into individual microservices.  It is also a convoluted example for purpose of brevity.

My final comment here is also to try not to reinvent the wheel (unless you are doing this as a learning exercise).  For instance, an authentication gateway is something that is well solved using industry standard tools and practices.  You can look to integrate with an existing Identity Provider service that implements OIDC and OAuth (Google, Facebook, etc...) or look at implementing existing software that supports these standards.

Comment: Cool, thanks for some detailed info. I'm still trying to fully understand microservices etc, so I'll probably look for some in-depth detailed writeups on it. Do you happen to know of any good sources for that?